# how to save layers in combobox

Tags: arcmap, c#, arcgis-engine

I'd like to develop an app so that user introduce the layers in comboboxes ( layers are slope,aspect,elevation etc) then user use these layers for processing in another form(processing form) and  dose not need to select the items in processing form . i don't know how can i write the code for saving the layers in comboboxes .

Can you recommend a solution for this app?

Answer (score 3):

On your comobo box SelectedIndexChanged event just assign your cbo text to a public shared variable:

```
g_strXYZ == this.cboXYZ.Text
```

You can then assign this varable to your other form control on the Load event.

```
this.cboOther.Items.Add(g_strXYZ)
```

Comment: and about save button ? how can i write code for button "ok" to save my layers in comboboxes?

Comment: i found it . i have to use xml to save layer and use it to pass to the another combobox .